# udev rules for multiple hokuyo LiDARS doesn't work: urg_node

Tags: ros, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am using multiple hokuyo lidars with nvidia TX2. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Linux for Tegra with Kinetic ROS distribution. I am trying to write a udev rule to create a symlink with the id.
this is what I have right now

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="15d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", MODE="0666", PROGRAM="/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/%k q", SYMLINK+="sensors/hokuyo_%c"
```

which is same as what is mentioned in the driver page. But unfortunately, the rule is'nt creating a symlink but the permissions for the file is applied. I am not sure what is happening.
Running `udevadm test -a add $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyACM1)` prints out the error. The relevant part of the output is

```
PROGRAM '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM1 q' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mapbaby.rules:5
starting '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM1 q'
'/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM1 q'(err) '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/urg_node/getID: error while loading shared libraries: liburg_c_wrapper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
Process '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM1 q' failed with exit code 127.
handling device node '/dev/ttyACM1', devnum=c166:1, mode=0660, uid=0, gid=20
preserve permissions /dev/ttyACM1, 020660, uid=0, gid=20
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/166:1' to '../ttyACM1'
found 'c166:1' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fserial\x2fby-id\x2fusb-Hokuyo_Data_Flex_for_USB_URG-Series_USB_Driver-if00'
found 'c166:0' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fserial\x2fby-id\x2fusb-Hokuyo_Data_Flex_for_USB_URG-Series_USB_Driver-if00'
creating link '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Hokuyo_Data_Flex_for_USB_URG-Series_USB_Driver-if00' to '/dev/ttyACM1'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Hokuyo_Data_Flex_for_USB_URG-Series_USB_Driver-if00' to '../../ttyACM1'
found 'c166:1' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fserial\x2fby-path\x2fplatform-3530000.xhci-usb-0:3.4.1:1.0'
creating link '/dev/serial/by-path/platform-3530000.xhci-usb-0:3.4.1:1.0' to '/dev/ttyACM1'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/serial/by-path/platform-3530000.xhci-usb-0:3.4.1:1.0' to '../../ttyACM1'
```

I'm not sure why the `liburg_c_wrapper.so` is failing. The program functions fine when executed from the terminal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270939/udev-rules-for-multiple-hokuyo-lidars-doesn%27t-work:-urg_node/) by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="15d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '$(find /opt/ros -name env.sh | sort -r | head -1) rosrun urg_node getID %N q'", SYMLINK+="sensors/hokuyo_%c"
```

udev rule from

> https://answers.ros.org/question/172765/giving-hokuyo-persistent-device-names/?answer=261632#post-id-261632

to solve the problem.

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) with karma: 78 on 2017-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cat_in_box](https://answers.ros.org/users/44444/cat_in_box/) on 2019-08-01**:
thanks for posting along with the reference - helped me compare udev rules to determine why mine wasn't working as I expected

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that udev run as root and don't have the `/opt/ros/dist/lib` in his shared object path.
I did :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /opt/ros/melodic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM0 q
H0508558
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ su
Mot de passe :
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# /opt/ros/melodic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM0 q
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/urg_node/getID: error while loading shared libraries: liburg_c_wrapper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/
root@raspberrypi:/opt/ros/melodic/lib# ldconfig /opt/ros/melodic/lib/
root@raspberrypi:/opt/ros/melodic/lib# /opt/ros/melodic/lib/urg_node/getID /dev/ttyACM0 q
H0508558`
```

---

Originally posted by [Octopic](https://answers.ros.org/users/50037/octopic/) with karma: 11 on 2020-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1